# Send Android Notifications(like SMS, Gmail, WhatsApp) to PC

Tags: applications, sms, notifications

Most of the time, when I keep my device for charging, away from my PC where I work, I get lot of notifications from things like Gmail, WhatsApp, SMS and Hangout, and other communication apps.

I know that I received these notifications because I do get sound alert whenever I receive them.

But I need to walk to my phone to see what those messages are and then take appropriate action if needed.

Is there a way to send or divert these device's notifications to my PC? And respond to them from PC itself?

```
My Android device: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2(Android 4.1)

My PC: Lenovo B40-30, Windows-8.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serach for apps who solve this problem like these:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rsupport.mvagent

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

**PUSHBULLET**: Pushbullet makes your devices work better together by allowing you to move things between them easily.
Never miss a call or text again while working at your computer.
See all of your phone's notifications on your computer. You can see text messages, phone calls, and more.

Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android